# Can TypeScript (d.ts) describe an anonymous method with typed args?

Tags: typescript

Why would ITreeArgs not exist in the export function definition (tree.d.ts file)?

```
interface ITreeArgs {
    mayHaveChildren: bool;
}

export function(args: ITreeArgs); <- The name 'ITreeArgs' does not exist in the current scope
```

these both work:

```
export function c(args: ITreeArgs); <- adding name works!
export function (args); <- removing type works!
```

Comment: To address the questions below, you would want to export something anonymously in a file.d.ts to support AMD modules which return a function.  E.g. dojo/ready.d.ts would contain "export function(f: Function)

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this (in dojo.d.ts file):

```
module "dojo/on" {
    function (target: Element, type: string, listener: (e: Event) => void);
}
```

Then I import it like this:

```
import on = module("dojo/on");
```

And use this module as pure function like this:

```
on(this.goButton, "click", this.ongo.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your function a name for it to be valid syntax - this is the real error.

`ITreeArgs` is available as adding a name shows.

```
interface ITreeArgs {
    mayHaveChildren: bool;
}

export function functionName(args: ITreeArgs) {
    //function body
}
```

I'm not sure what your reason is for wanting to leave out the function name?

Update: to declare a constructor on an interface, you use:

```
interface ITreeArgs {
    new (myArg: string);
}
```

To declare a constructor on a class in a definition file, you would use:

```
declare class MyClass {
     constructor(myArg: ITreeArgs);
}
```

It is not possible to declare a constructor on a module.

In the language specification, it says that you can leave out the `declare` keyword in a `.d.ts` file - but in practice I find that it makes things absolutely clear if someone hasn't spotted the file extension.

Comment: I neglected to mention this was a d.ts file!  I will fix the question.

Comment: I have added a note about defining constructors - they need to be defined in the context of a class or interface though.

Comment: The problem is you can't be compatible with existing dojo AMD this way...I need the ability to do import ready = module("dojo/ready") and then immediately use ready, e.g. ready(function() {}).  So I really am looking for an anonymous method on a module.  My title was inaccurate...not 'constructor' but 'method'.  I will correct the title.

Comment: You may need to just use JavaScript for this part (you can still do so in your TypeScript file): `declare function require(...params: any[]) : void;

require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){
    ready(function(){
        alert('ready');
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

name requirement is for export only because Typescript will add code

```
namespace.function_name = ...
```

so this is unclear why somebody wants to export something anonymously :)

but for example if you want return typed anonymous function from another function you can do it.

```
function foo() {
    return function(bar:string):string { return bar; }
}
```